# Sorting blocks of data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have data in Excel formatted like the example below, with blocks of information spread across 3 lines. Is there a way to sort the columns by one piece of data from a block? i.e. Sorting the blocks in column A by Teacher or Room?

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ClassA/Sc** | **ClassA/Sc** | **ClassB/Sp** |
| Teacher A | Teacher A | Teacher B |
| Room 1 | Room 1 | Room 2 |
| **ClassA/Hi** | **ClassA/En** | **ClassB/Sp** |
| Teacher C | Teacher D | Teacher B |
| Room 3 | Room 4 | Room 2 |
| **ClassA/Re** | **ClassA/Ge** | **ClassB/Ru** |
| Teacher C | Teacher B | Teacher F |
| Room 5 | Room 2 | Room 3 |

I am proficient in VBA, but I can't figure out any sorting method using that that would work for this kind of data arrangement.

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT: The result would have each column sorted independently based on one of the listed characters, so in the data above Column A can be seen to have been sorted by Room (1,3,5), while Column B is not (1,4,2).

Comment: What would the expected result be?

Comment: I've edited the question to try and give a bit more of an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Didn't see that there already an accepted answer when I started posting. I'll leave this answer up as an alternative approach.

---

Since we know that we need the data to be sorted as we add it to the array, I'd just use one of the available Sorted List classes. You'd have to include some information about the height of a record, and also some details about how to you want it to be stored back to the sheet.

In my example below, I use a SortedList class. A function takes the record "field" upon which we want to sort. So, if you want to sort based on Class, pass in 1 for the first element. For teacher, pass 2 for second element, etc. (I'd definitely include some bounds checking to make sure that someone doesn't pass too large a number.

Since the data ends up sorted, you can just push the data back to the sheet.

let me know if you have any follow up questions.

```
Const HEIGHT_OF_RECORD As Integer = 3

Private Function SortColumnCuston(rng As Range, nSortElement As Integer) As Object
    Dim oList As Object
    Dim oTempDict As Object
    Dim startingCell As Range
    
    'Below just takes the first cell of the passed range and stores it to a variable
    'Doesn't matter if it's actually range("A1")
    Set startingCell = rng.Range("A1")
    
    Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    
    For i = 0 To rng.Rows.Count - HEIGHT_OF_RECORD Step HEIGHT_OF_RECORD
        Set oTempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        oTempDict.Add "Class", startingCell.Offset(i).Value
        oTempDict.Add "Teacher", startingCell.Offset(i + 1).Value
        oTempDict.Add "Room", startingCell.Offset(i + 2).Value
        
        oList.Add rng.Range("A1").Offset(i + nSortElement - 1).Value, _
            oTempDict
    Next i
    
    Set SortColumnCuston = oList
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim oDang As Object
    Dim sortDestinationStart As Range
    
    Set oDang = SortColumnCuston(Range("A1:A9"), 3)
    
    'This is where you want to paste the sorted data.
    'Note: it WILL overwrite what's there now, so be aware
    'of formulas, etc.
    Set sortDestinationStart = Range("F1")
    
    For i = 0 To oDang.Count - 1
        sortDestinationStart.Offset(i * HEIGHT_OF_RECORD).Value = _
            oDang.GetByIndex(i)("Class")
        sortDestinationStart.Offset(i * HEIGHT_OF_RECORD + 1).Value = _
            oDang.GetByIndex(i)("Teacher")
        sortDestinationStart.Offset(i * HEIGHT_OF_RECORD + 2).Value = _
            oDang.GetByIndex(i)("Room")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to gather all the data into an array and making sure that I have all the data that belongs together in the same "line" plus adding column letter...

Then the first row would look like this:
A, ClassA/Sc, Teacher A, Room 1

Then I would use a bubble sort function to get the data in the correct order, and then print the data again on the worksheet..

I am not sure this would work but it sounds like a good idea to me :)

What do you think?

Comment: That could be an option, but I'm not sure how I would then sort the cells afterwards based on the newly sorted array. I could potentially then paste back into the range I suppose.... I'll have to give it a try!

Comment: Yeah exactly what I meant to say, just print the data again on the worksheet. Good luck!